# AS3 Error 1084 expecting rightparen before semicolon

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have been working in flash again! Back working on games again... this time a choose your path game, and it needs to *save*. To do this I've got a few classes going, and had quite a few errors... Then I ran into this error for seemingly no reason... It clams is in this section,

```
public class MenuScreen extends MovieClip {
static function checkData() 



    public function MenuScreen() {  


    }
        static function checkData()
    SharedObject.getLocal(userData:string);

    // Create a shared-object named "userData"
    mySharedObject=SharedObject.getLocal("userData");
```

More precisely *this* line:

```
SharedObject.getLocal(userData:string);
```

Now theres a bit of code at the top I left off yes, And I can provide the entire  code if it will help, But correct me if Im wrong the program isn't making sense! This has happened before, The solution being to completely redo the file, Retype the code, (NOT copy/paste) and Don't allow so many test exports to fail! So I know I've experienced this error as a misstate before. Is it a misstate this time? Thats why Im here... ...

Comment: @ Brian This goes right before I call for saved data. I thought I made that clear when I said I needed it to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not looks like an *AS3* class and that's not that obvious how it was supposed to look like. At least I can provide you fix with will compile:

```
class MenuScreen extends MovieClip 
{
    public function MenuScreen() 
    {  
    }

    public static function checkData():void
    {
        // Create a shared-object named "userData"
        mySharedObject=SharedObject.getLocal("userData"); 
    }
}
```

But note that function `checkData()` is not called.

Comment: This did not work. It acted like it worked, but then provided the very same error on the vary same line. I have a lot of additional code after this that I can include.

Comment: Well you fixed that but I have some new unrelated errors now, so... Well thanks! I might post again if I can't solve these new errors with some searching.

Comment: your code looks pretty malformed and contains lots of line with invalid syntax, probably result of some merge or may be random copy/paste. Try first to cleanup invalid syntax lines